# Export excel to csv

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I want to copy data from excel to. Below is how I want to copy the data. For example I want to copy data in cell `D4` of excel to `A4` in [csv](/questions/tagged/csv).

```
"Excel ---> CSV
"D4-->A4
"F4&all excluding the first character in G4-->B4
"K4-->E4
"L4-->F4
"N4-->G4
"P4-->I4
```

Below is my code. It creates and populates the data as I need except that it does not delete the first character in `G4` when copying to `B4` in `csv`. Can someone tell me how i need to change my code to implement this.

```
Sub csvfile()

Dim fs As Object
Dim a As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim X

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\" & Environ("username") & ".csv", True)
X = Range([d4], Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp)).Value2

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X) - 15
a.writeline X(lngRow, 1) & "," & X(lngRow, 3) & X(lngRow, 4) & ",,," & X(lngRow, 8) & "," & X(lngRow, 9) & "," & X(lngRow, 11) & ",," & X(lngRow, 13)
Next
a.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the fourth column (`G`) like so:

**full code**

```
Sub csvfile()

Dim fs As Object
Dim a As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim X

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\" & Environ("username") & ".csv", True)
X = Range([d4], Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp)).Value2

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X) - 15
If Len(X(lngRow, 4)) > 0 Then X(lngRow, 4) = Right$(X(lngRow, 4), Len(X(lngRow, 4)) - 1)
a.writeline X(lngRow, 1) & "," & X(lngRow, 3) & X(lngRow, 4) & ",,," & X(lngRow, 8) & "," & X(lngRow, 9) & "," & X(lngRow, 11) & ",," & X(lngRow, 13)
Next
a.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me a type mismatch.

Comment: fixed dodgey `)`. pls try again

Comment: says invalid procedure call or argument. Ive tried both ways.